# Simple query in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

I have a simple LibreOffice calc worksheet with 3 columns and 1000 rows.

I want to create a list of 1000 sentences which are created from the 3 columns using a certain template, e.g:

> "Person A lives in B and has phone number C"

Where the values of A, B and C come from the relevant columns.

This is easy to do in an SQL database, but is there a simple way to do this from within LibreOffice Calc (without needing to export to CSV and import to SQL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `concatenate` function, from the `Inset` --> `Functions` --> `Text` menu, e.g.

```
=CONCATENATE("Person ",A49," lives in ",B49," and has phone number ",C49)
```

where `A`,`B`,`C` are replaced by the appropriate column indices of your spreadsheet.